# How to gracefully set one of the OBUFDS output pins as unused without causing error during implementation phase in Xilinx Vivado using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I'm trying to get a modified version of [this HDMI protocol implementation](https://github.com/fcayci/vhdl-hdmi-out) running on FPGA board (pynq-z2). The edits to the project were not made by me, and as I was told were used without any issue before. The edits remove TMDS by driving negative phase channels with positive input.

When I try to run implementation phase for pynq-z2 (the board it was used with before)  it fails with error `[Place 30-379] Output of OBUF instance tmds_signaling/ser_b/obuf is not driving any port. This might lead to unplaceable/unroutable situation`.

I don't have very good understanding of VHDL, but from looking up some basic information I think I've pinpointed the problem. The issue seem to lie in the fact that Xilinx library component, OBUFDS (which seem to be the differential signal generator) doesn't drive any component with it's negative output. Signals which were mapped to it's output port are not used. I'm curious if I can somehow either suppress the error or deliberately pull up or down that output as I essentially want to void it.

I hope this question is sound, as I have very little experience with vhdl and may have misused terminology by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The obufds is designed to drive fpga output pins.

I can think of two ways out of this:

1. Tie the unused output of the obufds to an unused fpga output pin.  This would be an unused output at the top level of the fpga.
2. The buffer may not do much.  If that is the case then it can be replaced it with a straight piece of wire.  If you have a simulation then take a look at the input and the output that is used.  If the output is exactly the same as the input then there is a good chance it can be removed.